# What do you call documents and other material serving as the basis for a decision?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning, phrase-request

In my language, we have a word – *beslutsunderlag* – for documents and other material that are used as a basis for decisions (generally decisions made by an authority of some sort). For instance: when a company is about to hire a new member of staff, they would use applicants' CVs, interviews etc as "beslutsunderlag" for deciding whom to hire. When a company is considering terminating one of their local branches, they use financial reports, customer surveys etc as "beslutsunderlag" for their decision. And so on.

When I look up *beslutsunderlag* in bilingual dictionaries (tyda.se and bab.la) I get *decision basis*, which is the exact literal translation of *beslutsunderlag* (*beslut – decision; underlag – basis*), but quite frankly, sentences such as the following sound rather unidiomatic to me, and when I google different versions of them, I get pretty much no hits:

> From the decision basis, it is clear that...

> The decision basis should include information about...

> The committee will put together a new decision basis

In my quest for a proper translation, I've come across *decision guidance documents* (or *DGDs*), which seems to be used to some extent, but I'm not 100% sure it means the same thing as what I'm after.

So, my questions are:

1. Am I right that the above examples don't quite work?
2. Does *decision guidance documents* mean 'documents and other material collected by a decision-making body, upon which a formal decision will be based'?
3. If neither *decision basis* nor *decision guidance documents* works, what should I use instead?

Comment: Consider that the translation may not be the same in all contexts - for example, my inclination would be to replace _decision basis_ with _evidence_ in your first example, but the other two examples would need more contextual information.

Comment: I think you might be talking about [***policy documents***](https://resources.workable.com/tutorial/the-5-company-policies-you-need-to-have-in-writing) - documents defining ***corporate*** policy (not the *insurance policy* documents sent out to customers). These documents will give greater detail than a ***mission statement*** about how the company conducts itself. Corporate policy documents aren't that important for most contexts though - the board of directors can always overrule anything contained therein, and lesser people within the organisation 
 must follow the ***Staff Handbook***.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin So "decision guidance documents" does not work?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, no – that's not at all what I'm after... hm. When a company is about to hire a new member of staff, they would use applicants' CVs, interviews etc as "beslutsunderlag" for deciding whom to hire. When a company is considering terminating one of their local branches, they use financial reports, customer surveys etc as "beslutsunderlag" for their decision. And so on.

Comment: That looks to me like just any old collection of documents guiding and/or supporting a corporate decision. It's not like those financial reports and customer surveys were *created* in order to help management decide which and whether to close local branches, so they wouldn't normally have a specific "collective name" for when they ***are*** used in that way.

Comment: _Decision Guidance Documents_ wouldn't be idiomatic - but it would be OK to use, at least in formal contexts. However, this is a situation where English doesn't in practice have a single "go-to" expression for all the usages of the German word; different words or phrases will be used in different contexts.

Comment: ...but I am intrigued as to what one might call corporate reports and documents that *aren't* used in decision-making contexts. (Apart from the obvious - ***waste paper**!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Exactly! That's precisely what it is :) Only in my language we do have a specific word for this – for when "any old collection of documents" is used to support a decision :) As for your last comment – I like your sense of humour  :)))

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Hm – how annoying... So, would you say it's better to use individual paraphrases in each specific case, than to use "decision guidance documents"?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'm obviously not saying that *you* are annoying – only that it's annoying that there doesn't seem to be a word for this in English. And, by the way, "beslutsunderlag" is not German – it's Swedish :)

Comment: (I understood that you were referring to the lack of a single word/phrase in English as what was annoying; no need to apologize for that). Yes, it's definitely better - and _always_ more appropriate - to find the _right_ word/phrase _for the context_. (I'm also not sure why I read Google Translate as detecting German instead of Swedish. Fairly obvious that that was _my_ error, not Google's.)

Comment: Well, @AndyBonner has mentioned the collocation ***supporting documents*** in the context of "documents supporting a job application". But that's just a general-purpose collocation, which works just as well when referring to the information sources supporting / justifying a corporate decision. Though I'd return to my earlier observation - typically the board of directors would like to think *they make the decisions* (they don't just slavishly design current corporate policy by consulting documents written and/or endorsed by *previous* board members).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin :) And thanks!

Comment: I asked a friend whose job it is to collect, store and retrieve this type of documentation, and make recommendations on what pieces of such documentation to collect or present. She says there's no specific English word beyond "supporting documents".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right that a direct translation of "decision guidance documents" is not the best choice. It is certainly to-the-point, but since it's not an established or familiar phrase, its meaning isn't immediately obvious.

Unfortunately this is one of the many times that the best translation must do some rewording, rather than be very word-for-word. To the best of my knowledge there is no direct English corollary for "documents used as the basis for a decision" that fits all contexts generically. There are specialized terms for various contexts, though. For many of the instances you cite, "evidence" or "body of evidence" might be appropriate. "Supporting documents" can be appropriate when referring to less-important documents that accompany a more-important one ("please submit your resume and any supporting documents"). If the emphasis is on a collection of documents that have been brought together into a whole, "file" or "portfolio" are common. Here are some choices for specific scenarios:

- Interviewing a candidate for a job, to refer to the resume/cv/supporting documents: "Looking over your *qualifications*, I see..."
- Deciding to close a branch of a company: "In making this decision, please consider the *file* collected over the past year..." (This is another where "body of evidence" might make sense)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful!